# Can one put absolute values around the first two function terms in the Euler Maclaurin formula for the Riemann zeta function?

Tags: absolute-value, riemann-zeta, euler-maclaurin

I know by the Euler–Maclaurin formula that this is true for the Riemann zeta function:
$$\Re(s)>0:\;\;\;\; \zeta (s)=\lim_{k\to \infty } \, \left|\sum _{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{(s-1) k^{s-1}}\right| \;\;\;\;(\ast)$$

> My **question** is if one is allowed to split the absolute value function like this:

$$\Re(s)>0 \;\;\;\;  \zeta (s)=\lim_{k\to \infty } \, \left(\left|\sum _{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^s}\right|-\left|\frac{1}{k^{s-1} (s-1)}\right|\right) \;\;\;\;(\ast \ast)$$

I don't know any mathematical application for such a change other than that $(\ast \ast)$ seems to converge to $0$ slightly faster than the original $(\ast)$ formulation, when $s$ is a Riemann zeta zero.

---

```
(*Mathematica*)
(*start*)
Clear[x, k, j, s];
k = 10000;
s = N[ZetaZero[1], 50];
Abs[Sum[1/n^s, {n, 1, k}] + 1/k^(s - 1)/(s - 1)]
Abs[Sum[1/n^s, {n, 1, k}]] - Abs[1/k^(s - 1)/(s - 1)]
Abs[Sum[1/s^n, {n, 1, k}]] - Abs[1/k^(2 s - 1)/(s - 1)]
(*end*)
```

Output:

```
0.004999958472065407135120606606862217064524894
0.000177345880980905486884439449850700223059324
```

Comment: I messed up. The question is not exactly what I wanted to say. One needs to add the restriction that the variable $s$ has to be a Riemann zeta zero. But I don't want to bump this question to main.

Comment: not sure that I understand correctly the question as if $a_k+b_k \to 0$ then $|a_k|-|b_k| \to 0$ (faster than $a_k+b_k$ always) by the triangle inequality $||a_k|-|b_k| | \le |a_k+b_k| \to 0$ so if $\zeta(s)=0$ then the required limit is zero (and faster) by general principles; note that if $\zeta(s) \ne 0$ your first limit is not correct as $\zeta (s)=\lim_{k\to \infty } (\sum _{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{(s-1) k^{s-1}})$ without absolute values (for $\Re s >0$)